# MapDB deprecated functions

Tags: java, android, mapdb

I'm programming in Android Studio. I'm using the mapDB, 2.0-beta8 version.
I have created my own class SingleCase, I also defined a static variable:

```
static ConcurrentNavigableMap<String, SingleCase > map;
```

after initialize the data base:

```
db = DBMaker.fileDB(newFile(dbName)).closeOnJvmShutdown().encryptionEnable(dbName).make();
```

I tried to load to my map variable from data base by using that code:

```
map = db.getTreeMap("collectionName");
```

Unfortunately it fails, and alerts that 'getTreeMap(java.lang.String)' is deprecated.

what other function can I use instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
treeMap("Aa").createOrOpen()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use createOrOpen(), but I'm new in MapDB, so this could be a wrong.

[see docu](http://www.mapdb.org/javadoc/latest/mapdb/org/mapdb/DB.HashMapMaker.html#createOrOpen--)